# URL hyphenation

Tags: compiling, hyphenation, urls

I need to hyphenate an URL —I'm the using `\url{ }` command)—. I've found that one solution is to add the `hyphen` option to the `url` package. I've added it but the compilation doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package url.
```

Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

p.s The URL is contained in an entry of the bibliography. I don't know if this changes something. Here an example:

```
@misc{intro:naturaldisasters,
  title={The title},
  howpublished={\url{http://<URL TOO LONG>}},
  note={Accessed: YYYY-M-D}
}
```

Comment: First, you forgot to post the error message. Second, please provide an example code that shows the problem and can be run.

Comment: If you use `biblatex`, it defines a `url=` field, which hyphenates urls correctly.

Comment: @Bernard, I've put the URLs in the `howpublished=` field.

Comment: Try a direct `url={http://…},` with biblatex. For me, it works fine.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf, I'm sorry: a typo. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Bernard, the field `url=` is not printed in the output document.

Comment: "Option clash" means that you are loading the package twice but with different options.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I cannot find where it is loaded. :(

Comment: Your editor will have a search function, use it.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I know. I meant that in my main file there is only one inclusion of that package. I took a look at the class file but there isn't `url`.

Comment: So delete the one  you found.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I did. But this does not solve my problem!

Comment: Check the log-file. It tells you where url is loaded. Or provide a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks, @UlrikeFischer. I've chosen to use the `\href` command and it works because considers the label as a string.

Answer (score 5):

Because you gave no MWE it is hard to give you the right answer.

I guess that another package in your code has already called package `url`, so that your `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` results in a option clash (means `url` was called with different options).

Write the command `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}` in the line before `\documentclass[...]{...}`. Then your needed option `hyphens` is passed to package `url` when it is called.

Because you gave no MWE I can't say more, sorry.